# PCH File in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I save all my projects in /Users/UserA/Developers but where would the pch files be located in xcode 5?

I am trying to figure out some core data issues and wanted to add #import  to that file (is that necessary)?

Answer (score 3):

PCH or Prefix header file should be in `Supporting Files` group of the project. Open you project, go to Project Navigator section (or, press "CMND+1"), find `Supporting Files` group, open the group, there you should see file with `.pch` extension, that would be your PCH file. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check in the **settings** for the **Target**.

Choose **Target** in the **Groups and Files** pane on the left.
**Right-Click** and choose **Get Info**
Search for **"Info.Plist"** and type in the filename for the correct plist file into the property of the item named "Info.Plist File".

Then search for **"Prefix"** and find the item named **"Prefix Header".**

Change it's property to the name of the correct .pch file that you are using.
I think these different "Info" windows are confusing. You have to make sure the right file is selected in the Groups and Files pane before selecting "Get Info", and it's hard to tell if what you're doing is actually making changes to the Info.plist file, or where your changes are being saved.